# Connect PC to TV from VGA to HDMI

Tags: hdmi, vga, external-display, tv, ports

I have a PC unit with a VGA port to which I connect my monitor and it works with no problems. When I try to connect the same VGA port to the HDMI port from the TV (HDMI IN 2(DVI)) it doesn't display the image. I have a cable from VGA to VGA and from VGA to HDMI. Don't know if it's important but one minor detail I used TeamViewer to see the display when I connected the PC to the TV and I can see that it changes automatically the resolution to the TV resolution but I still can't see on the TV the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a converter to change the analogue VGA signal into a digital signal for HDMI. Just connecting cables and adapters together won't do anything.

Comment: I researched and found out that I actually have an HDMI to VGA converter, that converts digital HDMI input into an analog VGA output. Which doesn't do anything as you said. Didn't know about this before...